# Add Roles to User using checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I am developing a Razor application and I need the Admin to assign or update roles of the Users. I am using a checkbox to carry out this action. So far, I have been able to populate the view to show the users and their respective roles ticked in the checkbox, but I haven't been able to update their roles, as anytime a checkbox is ticked to add a role, it doesn't add the role to the user. I think this line is the culprit: `var selectedRoles = model.Where(x => x.Selected).Select(y => y.RoleName);`.

This is the Model:

```
public class ManageUserRolesViewModel
{
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Page:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h2>Manage User Roles</h2>
            Add / Remove Roles for @Model.UserID

        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            @foreach (var x in Model.UserRoles)
             {
                <div class="form-check m-1">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@x.RoleId" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@x.RoleName" />
                    <input asp-for="@x.Selected" class="form-check-input" />
                    <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@x.Selected">
                        @x.RoleName
                    </label>
                </div>
             }
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:auto" />
            <a asp-page="/Account/UserManagement/UserList" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:auto">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the Page Model:

```
public class ManageModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly BankAssesmentApplicationIdentityDbContext _db;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

        public ManageModel(
         RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
         UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
         BankAssesmentApplicationIdentityDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }

        public IList<ManageUserRolesViewModel> UserRoles = new List<ManageUserRolesViewModel>();
        public string UserID { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(List<ManageUserRolesViewModel> model, string userId)
        {
            UserID = userId;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                IdentityUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userId);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    return Page();
                }

                var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                var result = await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, roles);

                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Cannot remove user existing roles");
                    return Page();
                }

                var selectedRoles = model.Where(x => x.Selected).Select(y => y.RoleName);

                await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, selectedRoles);

                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Cannot add selected roles to user");
                    return Page();
                }

                return RedirectToPage("/Account/UserManagement/UserList");
            }

            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId)
        {
            UserID = userId;

            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            var model = new List<ManageUserRolesViewModel>();
            foreach (var role in _roleManager.Roles.ToList())
            {
                ManageUserRolesViewModel roles = new ManageUserRolesViewModel
                {
                    RoleId = role.Id,
                    RoleName = role.Name,
                };
                UserRoles.Add(roles);

                if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
                {
                    roles.Selected = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    roles.Selected = false;
                }
                model.Add(roles);
            }
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you get selectedRoles.ToList().Count if you try it from debug mode?

Comment: @coder_b It says Count = 0

Comment: hmm.. hope this would help to resolve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783005/using-a-checkbox-list-with-razor-pages-for-input-to-db

Comment: @coder_b Thanks man, but this doesn't really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firsly,you need know that for each property of the complex type, model binding looks through the sources for the name pattern `prefix.property_name`. If nothing is found, it looks for just `property_name` without the prefix.Your backend wants to receive a list model,so what you pass should be `[index].PropertyName`.But what you did will result in serveral inputs with the same name,the model binding system could not match the value for the list.

Then you need know that `asp-for="@x.Selected"` will generate the value for checkbox,but it will not change the value when you change the checkbox state,you need create a click event to change the value:

```
<input asp-for="@x.Selected" onclick="$(this).val(this.checked ? true : false)"/>
```

What you need change like below:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h2>Manage User Roles</h2>
            Add / Remove Roles for @Model.UserID

        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
        @*Begin change*@
            @{ int i = 0;}
            @foreach (var x in Model.UserRoles)
            {               
                <div class="form-check m-1">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@x.RoleId" name="[@i].RoleId"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@x.RoleName" name="[@i].RoleName"/>
                    <input asp-for="@x.Selected" name="[@i].Selected" class="form-check-input" onclick="$(this).val(this.checked ? true : false)"/>
                    <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@x.Selected">
                        @x.RoleName
                    </label>
                </div>
                i++;
            }
         @*End change*@
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:auto" />
            <a asp-page="/Account/UserManagement/UserList" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:auto">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@user:3843256 have a look at this sample it works ok, the only difference is you are using for each, that means bind does not take place, change to counter based index binding

[Checkbox list binding](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wihixP)

Comment: I just ran your fiddle, the RoleName produces a null value

Comment: that's doesn't' matter really since I was binding to label it is not posting, I  hope no one is going to change role name isn't'? you after selected field to update your use object